# How to use `netstat' to show utun (socket) interfaces?

Tags: network, command-line, macos

I've looked through help using `help netstat` and can't see a way to just show tun interfaces (or sockets).

I found one `netstat` option that isn't listed in the help, `netstat -u` which only shows "Active LOCAL (UNIX) domain sockets".

I can grep the results of that command for ".sock" but would like to only one command.

I am wondering if there are any more "unlisted" netstat options for the mac version of netstat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man-page for `netstat` lists these options:

A, a, b, c, d, f, g, I, i, L, l, ll, lll, m, n, p, q, r, R, s, S, v, W, w, x and z.

The source code for `netstat` lists these options:

A, a, b, c, d, F, f, g, I, i, L, l, ll, lll, m, n, P, p, Q, q, r, R, s, S, t, u, v, W, w, x and z

So the unlisted `netstat` options are: F, P, Q, t and u.

You have already discovered `u`, which means to list only AF_UNIX sockets.

The rest have this meaning:

- F: Show interface forwarded packets
- P: Show packet priority statistics
- Q: Opportunistic polling stats display
- t: Show interface watchdog timers

This means that there's no "secret" option that will make `netstat` output what you desire. You can either use a different (probably custom made) tool, or parse its output with tools like `grep`.

For example you could dig information about `utun` interfaces out of the System Configuration daemon by running a command like this:

```
echo list "State:/Network/Interface/utun.*" | scutil
```

The `scutil` commands also allows you to watch for changes, so that you can run the command in the background and report whenever an interface is created or destroyed.

Comment: Where would a user find the source code for BSD netstat? I think it's BSD... Any idea on how to show only "utun" interfaces using CLI on Mac?

Comment: I'm still writing on the answer - hold on.

Comment: I have completed the answer for now. There's no secret "utun only" option. Can you elaborate on why you need this - perhaps there's an easier way to solve your problem.

Comment: Regarding the source code: It's not really "the BSD netstat" - yes, the original program came from BSD and was forked from there at the time. But that was 1993/1994 - a long time has passed. You need to look for Apple's netstat instead. It's available on Apple's open source page (opensource.apple.com).

Comment: When I connect to my VPN provider. They create a utun interface that creates another utun interface for me to use. I am looking for a way to “get” that utun info

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? - Sounds a bit unconventional? - Do you just need to get the utun number for adding some extra routes? - or what is the purpose?

Comment: Which VPN client do you use?

Comment: I use PIA. It has some CLI commands but not which utun interfaces it creates.

Comment: I have added a suggestion to use scutil for this purpose.